# Abstract Matrix Algebra and Calculus in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, derivative, mathematical-expressions

I am doing control engineering and I often face problems of the type below and I want to know if there is a way to deal with this in sympy.

*question:*
tl:dr: I want to make a `MatrixSymbol` dependent on a scalar `Symbol` representing time, to allow differentiation w.r.t. time.

Actual problem: `v(t)=[v1(t),v2(t),v3(t)]` is a vector function of the time `t` and I want to calculate the Projection into the direction of v and it's time derivative. In the end I would love to get an expression of `v`, `v.diff(t)` and `v.T` (the transpose).

*attempts:*

I've tried different things and show the closest one:

This does the algebra I need, but I cannot take derivatives w.r.t. time

```
v = MatrixSymbol('v',3,1) 

# here i'm building the terms I want
projection_v = v*sqrt(v.T*v).inverse()*v.T
orthogonal_v = Identity(3)-projection_v

orthogonal_v.as_explicit()
```

`orthogonal_v` shows the abstract equation form that I need. In the end - to check and see the result again, I'd also like to make it explicit and see the expression as a function of `v[0,0]`, `v[1,0]`, and `v[2,0]` for MatrixSymbol the function `.as_explicit()` does exactly that beginning with sympy version 1.10. (Thanks Francesco Bonazzi for pointing this out.)

The problem however is, that I cannot make these a function of `t` and take the derivative of `projection_v` w.r.t. the time `t`.

I also tried

```
t = Symbol('t',real=True,positive=True)
v1 = Function('v1',real=True)(t)
v2 = Function('v2',real=True)(t)
v3 = Function('v3',real=True)(t)
v_mat = FunctionMatrix(3,1,[v1,v2,v3]);
```

but it seems `FunctionMatrix` is meant to evaluate the functions directly instead of being an analog to the scalar `Function`.

Effectively I want to be able to calculate `orthogonal_v.diff(t)` and then see the component wise operations with something like `orthogonal_v.diff(t).as_explicit()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest SymPy version (1.10) and repeat you computations?

Comment: Almost there, thanks for the tip! The display is really nice. However, a key feature for my problems is to make a MatrixSymbol a function of 't' and take the derivative w.r.t. this symbol. You can do this with Matrix entries, but I found no way to achieve this with a MatrixSymbol.

Comment: I've opened a feature request on git: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23221